# Make code be more in functional-style

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

Here is Java-Scala code:

```
class MyDbManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper ....
val cursor = new MyDbManager().getReadableDatabase.query(....)
val result = new ArrayList[MyItem] //???

//?????????
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    result + parse(cursor)
  } while (cursor.moveToNext())
}
//?????????

cursor.close()
result
```

What I want to do is to be able not to use any mutable collection and immutable one with a mutable variable. I want to do something like this:

```
val result = if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do { parse(cursor) } while (cursor.moveToNext())
}
```

You got the idea: not using any redundant variables, especially mutable. Of course, code above won't compile.

How can I do this if it's possible? I'd like to do it **without** involving any third-party libraries, as simple as possible.

**update**:
"for" was suggested. since "for" translates to "map" and "filter" in my case, I wonder, why doesn't this work:

```
if.(cursor.moveToFirst()) cursor.filter(_.moveToNext()).map { x => parse(x) }
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult: a db cursor is inherently an imperative construct. You could use a `fold` passing along the cursor if you want to avoid imperative loops.

Comment: Or if you wish to use `filter`, you could use a predicate always resolving to `true` to get all the rows of the query.

Comment: Try defining a new class extending your cursor class with the `scala.collection.Iterator` trait. You then just need to define the `hasNext` and `next()` methods and you should be good to go with a for-comp

Answer (score 1):

This code is based on a `java.sql.ResultSet`, but the pattern should be applicable to your case as well.

### Option 1: Provide a foreach method

You can define a class like this:

```
class Cursor[T](rs: ResultSet)(f: Row => T) {
  def foreach(g: T => Unit) {
    val row = new Row(rs)
    while (rs.next()) {
      g(f(row))
    }
  }
}
```

It gets two arguments:

- The underlying result set
- A function `f` which produces an instance for each row. So during iteration, instances based on the current row are constructed.

The `Cursor` class provides a `foreach` method. So it can be used in a "for comprehension":

```
val cursor = Cursor(rs) {
  row =>
    Person(row.getString(1), row.getString(2))
}

for {
  person <- cursor
} {
  println(person)
}
```

---

To be able to use the `{ ... }` syntax for the function `f`, a companion object is required:

```
object Cursor {
  def apply[T](rs: ResultSet)(f: Row => T) = {
    new Cursor(rs)(f)
  }
}
```

A wrapper class `Row` representing a row of the result set is used, because some methods of the underlying result set should not be visible to the function (like `next()`).

```
class Row(rs: ResultSet) {
  def getString(n: Int) = rs.getString(n)
  def getInt(n: Int) = rs.getInt(n)
  // ... more getters for other types
}
```

### Option 2: Extend Iterator

```
class CursorWithIterator[T](rs: ResultSet)(f: Row => T) extends Iterator[T] {
  private val row = new Row(rs)

  override def hasNext = rs.next()

  override def next() = f(row)
}
```

You can use an `Iterator` in a for "comprehension" as well. And it gives you access to the full collection API like `map` etc.